# Windows app: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdiplus.h': No such file or directory

Tags: vidyo

I was trying to compile the windows application for visual studio 2017 and I'm coming across this:

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gdiplus.h': No such file or directory

I've tried searching for where to download this file but I can't seem to find it. I contacted vidyo and they redirected me to this link but I don't understand what to do with the file. It compiles and then runs without any real effect.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/GDI-bb1a3ba3

Anyone have any insights?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying out the [vidyo.io](https://vidyo.io) Windows sample project. This sample project was probably compiled to an older version of Windows SDK, so you can either try it on an older version of Visual Studio, or the better approach would be to retarget the sample project in Visual Studio,  so that it would refer to the newer Windows SDK.  Here are the steps to follow:

1. Go to the "Solution Explorer" view.
2. Right-click the "VidyoConnector15" solution or the "VidyoConnector" project icon.
3. In the context menu, select "Retarget solution" or "Retarget Projects", respectively.
4. In the resulting dialog, the preselected option is probably a newer Windows SDK version that is already installed on your computer.  Accept that option, and let Visual Studio update the sample project.
5. Built the app without errors.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help Sachin!